# Most Efficient Way to Automate Grouping of List Entries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, coordinates

**Background:**
I have a very large list of 3D cartesian coordinates, I need to process this list to group the coordinates by their Z coordinate (ie all coordinates in that plane). Currently, I manually create groups from the list using a loop for each Z coordinate, but if there are now dozens of possible Z (was previously handling only 2-3 planes)coordinates this becomes impractical. I know how to group lists based on like elements of course, but I am looking for a method to automate this process for n possible values of Z.
**Question:**
What's the most efficient way to automate the process of grouping list elements of the same Z coordinate  and then create a unique list for each plane?

**Code Snippet:**
I'm just using a simple list comprehension to group individual planes:

 
    `newlist=[x for x in coordinates_xyz if insert_possible_Z in x]`

 I'm looking for it to automatically make a new unique list for every Z plane in the data set.

**Data Format:**
`((x1,y1,0), (x2, y2, 0), ... (xn, yn, 0), (xn+1,yn+1, 50),(xn+2,yn+2, 50), ... (x2n+1,y2n+1, 100), (x2n+2,y2n+2, 100)...)`etc. 
I want to automatically get all coordinates where Z=0, Z=50, Z=100 etc. Note that the value of Z (increments of 50) is an example only, the actual data can have any value.
**Notes:**
My data is imported either from a file or generated by a separate module in lists. This is necessary for interface with another program (that I have not written).

Comment: Can you post your current code? How are the coordinates stored right now? list?dict?tuple?

Comment: Added a snippet for clarity :)

Comment: Is the Z-data continuous or discrete?  If it is continuous, do you need to bin the data by a predefined range?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to group elements by Z and make a list of them so grouped is to not make a list.

[itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does the grouping you want without the overhead of creating new lists.

Python generators take a little getting used to when you aren't familiar with the general mechanism. The [official generator documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is a good starting point for learning why they are useful.

Comment: Hi, I'm taking your advice and trying to get familiar with using generators (after reading the documentation I realise there are several areas of my code that would be better suited to using them), I was just wondering if it was possible to post a brief example of how best to do use groupby? I've tried to implement it as in the documentation but it's not working as I expected, and I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Please add the relevant lines that are "not working as expected" to your question, or perhaps open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting this correctly, you have a set of coordinates C = (X,Y,Z) with a discrete number of Z values.  If this is the case, why not use a dictionary to associate a list of the coordinates with the associated Z value as a key?

You're data structure would look something like:

```
z_ordered = {}
z_ordered[3] = [(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),(x3,y3,z3)]
```

Where each list associated with a key has the same Z-value.

Of course, if your Z-values are continuous, you may need to modify this, say by making the key only the whole number associated with a Z-value, so you are binning in increments of 1.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the simple solution I came up with:

```
groups=[]
groups[:]=[]
No_Planes=#Number of planes
dz=#Z spacing variable here

for i in range(No_Planes):
    newlist=[x for x in coordinates_xyz if i*dz in x]
    groups.append(newlist)
```

This lets me manipulate any plane within my data set simply with `groups[i]`. I can also manipulate my spacing. This is also an extension of my existing code, as I realised after reading @msw's response about itertools, looping through my current method was staring me in the face, and far more simple than I imagined!